# Chaos Monkey operability with Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, chaos

Does anyone have experience using Chaos Monkey with Kubernetes?  Curious as to how Chaos Monkey is setup, the outputs, reports, etc.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using kube-monkey (https://github.com/asobti/kube-monkey)